# Call to requests.get(...) kills thread randomly. Why?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-requests, python-multithreading

I have a **Python 2.7 script** in which I'm making GET calls using `requests.get(...)` to a lot of servers in a sequential manner. Sometimes however, the thread in which I'm making the calls gets killed while making the `requests.get(...)` call, and I'm not sure why. I know this because I printed logs before and after making the call, and the last log entry is always the one before making a call. Calls are made using the following command:

```
r = requests.get("http://" + node.hostname + ":2082/api/config", timeout=1)
```

This is the basic skeleton of the method making the calls:

```
def refresh_current_configs(number):
    while True:
        try:
            for node in nodes:
                try:
                    r = requests.get("http://" + node.hostname + ":2082/api/config", timeout=1)
                except (ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.Timeout) as e:
                    unreachable_nodes.add(node.hostname)
                    continue

                # Do processing

        except Exception,e:
            logger.error(e + " -- " + str(number))
        time.sleep(1000)
```

This is how I'm creating a thread in which to run `refresh_current_configs` method in the main thread:

```
consumer = threading.Thread(target=refresh_current_configs,args=(number,),name='config_refresher')
consumer.start()
```

**Any ideas why calls to `requests.get(...)` is randomly killing the thread in which the call is made ?**

Comment: How do you detect it has been killed?

Comment: `refresh_current_configs` writes to a log regularly (not shown in above skeleton). If the last write by `config_refresher` thread is like 5 hours ago, I'm guessing the thread was killed.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is going on, but `requests.get` can't "kill" the thread. Maximum it can do is to throw an exception, but you have a catch block that keeps the loop running. Could it be that the threads are created as daemons and the parent threads finishes without waiting for its children to finish?

Comment: You should check the OS log for any hint why the process got killed. And you should run it in an open terminal session.

Comment: No that's not possible because the the `config_refresher` thread isn't a daemon thread.

Comment: @KlausD., process isn't killed since other 2 threads in it keep running. Only this `config_refresher` thread is getting killed.

Comment: Is it possible that `unreachable_nodes.add(node.hostname)` raises exception? In that case you're not catching it, so thread will be killed